# How to get the .config from a Linux kernel image?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kbuild

I have a Linux kernel image in elf format and I want to find out what `.config` file was used to build this kernel. When I do an **objdump** of the image, I see a section called `kernel_config_data` that contains text but does not look like the config file. Is there a way to retrieve this information?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Assuming your kernel was built with the [IKCONFIG](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/linux_kernel/kernel_configuration/re139.html) option, you can use the `scripts/extract-ikconfig` tool to extract the original `.config` file.

Alternately, you can boot that kernel and find the embedded configuration in `/proc/config.gz`.

Comment: And how to check if it was built w/ IKCONFIG ? I guess if ikconfig just fail : like

    scripts/extract-ikconfig $file
    extract-ikconfig: Cannot find kernel config.

Comment: @Frederic Hamidi   I have some `.img` files which are `arm-eabi-gcc` cross compiled and I want to get the `.config` file of that images. Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 3):

You can `zcat` `/proc/config.gz`, for example:

```
zcat /proc/config.gz | grep 'CONFIG_PRINTK_TIME'
```

To dump this into the `.config` used in the kernel build process:

```
zcat /proc/config.gz > .config
```